# Return object with highest key/value pairs from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

Given an array of objects, I want to return an object with the highest values from all the objects.

```
let countObj = [{2:1},{2:4, 5:1},{3:3}]
let finalObj = {}
let primes = [2,3,5]
// finalObj should return {2:4, 3:3, 5:1}
```

I feel like there should be some way to use the primes array and reduce on the countObj to get the desired result.

```
primes.forEach(p => countObj.reduce((a,b) =>{
                 if (a[p]){ //if prime no. exists as key in a
                      a[p] > b[p] ? //keep key/val pair in a : replace key/val pair
                    }else{ //if new prime is not a key in a
                      a[p] = b[p]
                    }    
               },{})
```

I'm not sure if the logic is correct and also, I don't know how to get it to return the final object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the stored value is greater than the actual value and if not, then assign the value to the result set.

```js
var countObj = [{ 2: 1 }, { 2: 4, 5: 1 }, { 3: 3 }],
    finalObj = {};

countObj.forEach(o => Object.keys(o).forEach(k => finalObj[k] > o[k] || (finalObj[k] = o[k])));

console.log(finalObj); // { 2:4, 3: 3, 5: 1 }
```

With `primes`

```js
var countObj = [{ 2: 1 }, { 2: 4, 5: 1 }, { 3: 3 }],
    finalObj = {},
    primes = [2, 3, 5]

countObj.forEach(o => primes.forEach(k => k in o && (finalObj[k] > o[k] || (finalObj[k] = o[k]))));

console.log(finalObj); // { 2:4, 3: 3, 5: 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with your tests: 0 is the same as a missing value. And when using `reduce`, you must return the accumulator object.

I'd reduce on the objects instead of reducing on the primes:

```
let finalObj = countObj.reduce((f, o)=>{
    primes.forEach(k=>{
       if (k in o && !(o[k]<f[k])) f[k]=o[k];
    });
    return f;
}, {});
```

Comment: Why doesn't removing the ! and flipping the > work? ie if (k in o && (o[k]>f[k])) f[k]=o[k]

Comment: @IsabellaChen Because it's not the same when o[k] or f[k] is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested `foreach` like this.

In this case you do not need `primes[]`

```js
let countObj = [{
  2: 1
}, {
  2: 4,
  5: 1
}, {
  3: 3
}];
let finalObj = {};
let primes = [2, 3, 5];

countObj.forEach(function(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    var finalObjValue = finalObj[key] || 0;
    if(obj[key] > finalObjValue)
      finalObj[key] = obj[key];
  });
});

console.log(finalObj);
```

Comment: This won't work for negative numbers (which may or not be relevant for OP, but I'm not sure it's obvious for you)

Comment: @DenysSéguret Why ?

Comment: Because they're not > 0. Just test with {3:-1} instead of {3:3}.